# JQuery: how to retrieve the id of a C# dynamically created checkbox

Tags: jquery

I'm dynamically generating checkboxes on my asp page using the following code in the page_load event:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 23; i < 30; i++)
        {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            cb.ID = "chkd" + i.ToString();
            cb.Text = "WI " + i.ToString();
            cb.AutoPostBack = true;
            cb.CssClass = "myCheckBoxes";
            Panel1.Controls.Add(cb);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to use JQuery to execute a stored procedure based on the id of the checkbox that was clicked.  However, the id of the box that was clicked is always an empty string.  I'm just getting my feet wet with JQuery so any help would be appreciated.  Below is my JQuery code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".myCheckBoxes").click(function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "idChecker.aspx",
                data: "id=" + $(this).val(),
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg != "None" && !$("#chkd" + msg).is(':checked')) {
                        $("#chkd" + msg).trigger('click');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Could you post the html from the .net code?

Answer (score 1):

`data: "id=" + $(this).val()` will give you the value of the check box. If you want the ID, try

```
data: "id=" + $(this).attr('id')
```

Comment: Are you sure that your click event is fired?

Answer (score 1):

to get The id of you checkbox Try This

```
data: "id=" + $(this).prop("id"); // if you use jquery 1.6.2
```

or

```
data: "id=" + $(this).attr("id"); // if you use old version
```

**Update**
 I tried your scripts and noted that the `.Net` generated html for your `CheckBox` as `<span>` with class name `myCheckBoxes` and it contains two controls one is your checkbox and a `<label>` for checkbox text. So your javascript action is binded to `span` because it has the class name that defined in your selector and it has not id.

```
  <span class="myCheckBoxes">
    <input id="MainContent_chkd26" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chkd26">
    <label for="MainContent_chkd26">WI 26</label>
  </span>
```

to get your checkbox id you should modify your selector to get the checkbox inside your span. you can get it using one of the following samples

```
$(".myCheckBoxes input:checkbox")
$(".myCheckBoxes input[type=checkbox]")
$(".myCheckBoxes").find("input[type=checkbox]")
```

Comment: Apart of the name, is there a difference between `prop`and `attr`?

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.6.2 and I have tried both of these and still get the same result.  It's almost like jquery can't access the id because the controls are being generated on the server.

Comment: maybe it's something wrong with my code that I call on the page load event from Jquery.  the code is as follows:

Answer (score 0):

Replace $(this).val() with $(this).attr('id')

Comment: to get the id being passed from jquery to my Page Load event I'm using Request["id"] and attempting to pass this value to my stored proc. This is coming up empty.  I don't know how to watch the Jquery code to ensure that the This object is not null. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify slightly to debug:
note that `$(this).attr("id");`  or `$(this).prop("id");` depending on the version of jQuery.  Note to used .prop() if possible as 1.6.2 .attr() simply calls that if it can so you avoid a step.

I DO think you might use a web service OR a page method rather than return the entire page (*but I do NOT know your entire solution either ) (see below)

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".myCheckBoxes").click(function (event) {
        var pString = '{"id":"' + $(this).prop("id") + '"}';
    //alert(pString);//uncomment to debug
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "idChecker.aspx/checkId",
          data: pString,
          success: function (msg) {
            if (msg != "None" && !$("#chkd" + msg).is(':checked')) {
              $("#chkd" + msg).trigger('click');
            }
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

assumption: - AND additional advice you did NOT ask for directly.
Your server code looks for an 'id' string.
example of that in a PAGE METHOD:
in your .cs file for the page:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string checkId(string id)
{
    return id;
}
```

(be sure to put the web.config setting in to allow this) Ignore if this is not the way you want to go on this :)

```
<system.web>
   <httpModules>
     <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
   </httpModules>
 </system.web>
```

And the last tidbit, with jQuery 1.6.2 you can modify (slightly) the ajax call to account for the way asp.net returns data.  change these parts and add a converter:

```
dataType: "jsond",
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json",
converters: {
  "json jsond": function(msg) {
    return msg.hasOwnProperty('d') ? msg.d : msg; 
 }
},
```